# php.ini: what i must change, to write <? instead <?php?

Tags: php

in my local hosting the script doesn't work, if i wrote `<?` instead of `<?php`.

what i must change in `php.ini` to correct it?

Thanks

Comment: For portability's sake, don't enable short tags! (Oscar Wilde, 1747)

Comment: I find it barely makes any difference to my work flow typing <?php instead of <?, so don't bother using them and think of the portability! (John, Chapter 5 verse 12) ;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php

```
short_open_tag
```

Is the property you seek.

Comment: Sure, It must be ON to allow <?. Just keep in mind it's for php < 5.3.0 as specified in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

It is:

[`short_open_tag`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php)

Make sure to read:

- [PHP Short Open Tag: Convenient Shortcut or Short Changing Security?](http://perishablepress.com/press/2009/01/12/php-short-open-tag/)

Answer (score -1):

It's already been said how to do it, but I'm just saying that it might not be such a great idea. Almost anyone you ask will tell you not to use short tags. Unless you have a specific reason to use short tags, you should just type `<?php`. It's only 3 more characters.